# Django_extensions failing to work with iPython notebook

Tags: django, virtualenv, jupyter-notebook, django-extensions

I am using Django 1.4.5 and have just installed django-extensions, in a virtualenv. I am using Python 2.7.1. When I type:

```
./manage.py shell_plus --notebook
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/Users/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions/management/commands/shell_plus.py", line 140, in handle_noargs
    run_notebook()
  File "/Users/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_extensions/management/commands/shell_plus.py", line 71, in run_notebook
    from IPython.frontend.html.notebook import notebookapp
ImportError: No module named IPython.frontend.html.notebook
```

Without the `--notebook` option it works fine.  Also, `ipython notebook` works fine too.

Can anyone suggest what might be going wrong?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by using a new virtualenv, and making sure I had installed iPython in it, i.e:

```
pip install tornado
pip install pyzmq
pip install ipython
./manage.py shell_plus --notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what user [[https://stackoverflow.com/users/905720/racing-tadpole]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/905720/racing-tadpole)(Racing Tadpole) said above, I also had to install jinja2.

```
pip install jinja2
```

A way to test what is missing to have django shell_plus on ipython notebook is trying to execute ipython notebook alone. This way I could detect all missing libraries, like jinja2.

```
ipython notebook
```

If this works, your chances are high that shell_plus --notebook will also work.